# Typecasting class variables php

Tags: php, oop

It should be a triviality, but I haven't found the right syntax for typecasting class variables in PHP. I've tried like this:

```
public int $approved;
```

and

```
public (int) $approved;
```

but both ways the script does not run. I have lots of names, so seeing the data type visually in the code would help distinction. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no syntax to accomplish what you want in the class declaration itself. However, the community is coalescing to a large degree around the documentation specs [laid out by phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/var.html).  In your case, you would use a `@var` keyword in the property's doc block.

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
public $approved;
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected static $othervar;
```

If you'd like to see an example of well-documented code using this method, I would recommend looking over [the Symfony Framework codebase](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) (although they may not always document class properties).

You won't be able to  coerce the type to `int` when writing to the properties, unless you made them `private` and created a setter to coerce them [via `__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set). That that's inflexible because you would need to account for lots of different types.  PHP is dynamically typed; most attempts to make it behave otherwise are likely to be fraught with frustration.

Comment: `@access` and `@static` seems mildly redundant.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast It isn't for your eyes, it is for the phpDocumentor _parser_. It reads doc blocks, it does not parse the code itself.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Unless maybe those are deprecated... I don't see them [in the current list](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html)  Yeah, maybe they're gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah no, PHP does not have strong typing (it will convert any variable into what it's used like).

All you can do is write

```
public $approved;
```

and remember that you want to store numeric values in it (when they're coming from a database, PHP might even store the value as a string and implicitly convert to int as soon as you're starting to calculate with it).

Some editors support phpdoc-like hints that can help you remember which variable is which type like:

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
public $approved;
```

But this is not standard behaviour.

In any way, there is no way of consistently forcing PHP into using only one type on  a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everybody has said, I would like to add this:

In you really need a true INT (no a string representing a number) then you can make use of [intval](https://www.php.net/intval)